# dynamic path with languages rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have these routes:

```
job_de_path GET  /de/jobs/:id(.:format)  jobs#show {:locale=>"de"}
job_en_path GET  /en/jobs/:id(.:format)  jobs#show {:locale=>"en"}
```

Each job object have an attribute `locale` with `"en"` or `"es"` values.

I would like generate a dynamic path depending on the locale attribute of each job, something like:

```
<%= link_to, "job 1", job_"#{job.locale}"_path(job) %>
```

but I get syntax error.

```
syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
```

**Thanks!**

Comment: what's the error mention also here...

Comment: with `job_"#{job.locale}"_path(job)`I get syntax error! `syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('` thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the standard "I need to call a method by name but the name is in a String" trick:

```
<%= link_to, "job 1", send("job_#{job.locale}_path", job) %>
```

or better (IMO), set up your routes using a scope:

```
scope '(:locale)' do
  # Locale-less routes go here...
end
```

and then you'll have a simple `job_path` helper that takes the locale as an argument:

```
<%= link_to 'job 1', job_path(job.locale, job) %>
```

Comment: The `<%= link_to, "job 1", send("job_#{job.locale}_path", job) %>` fixed the error :) Thank you very much!